# RobotFrameWork:: Execution in Firefox throws keyError: 'Value" Error for every execution

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, geckodriver, selenium2library

Attached is the pkgs installed with our project setup..[image]
and we cant upgrade our pkgs due to some reasons.

I tried to run the in these combinations FFv53,54,55,56 with gecko driver 16,19

This is the error message from PyCharm:

```
==============================================================================
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
Ping Endpoint2222 :: Sends and verifies a ping command for some en... | FAIL |
Setup failed:
KeyError: 'value'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Commands.Ping :: Ping Command                                         | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Geckodriver logs:

```
1510747591183   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:65395
1510747593075   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser \\?\D:\Program Files\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1510747594386   addons.manager  DEBUG   Application has been upgraded
1510747594387   addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70"  data: no] Stack trace: FileUtils_getDir()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:70 < FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 < validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:671 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:834 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3129 < observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:65
1510747594389   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 1657: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
1510747598397   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 65402
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2570: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
1510747598952   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
1510747658086   addons.productaddons    INFO    sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/53.0/20170413192749/WINNT_x86_64-msvc-x64/en-US/release/Windows_NT%206.1.1.0%20(x64)/default/default/update.xml
1510747659578   addons.productaddons    INFO    Completed downloading document
1510747660101   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1510747660112   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to C:\Users\bbanduch\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpaddon-6363aa
1510747663032   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1510747663036   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to C:\Users\bbanduch\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpaddon-ce3de3
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 1416: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
 app-system-defaults
1510747289405   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1510747289407   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1510747289407   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on firefox@getpocket.com installed in app-system-defaults
1510747289413   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1510747289413   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on webcompat@mozilla.org installed in app-system-defaults
1510747289417   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1510747289421   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1510747289425   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1510747289425   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering startup change 'installed' for aushelper@mozilla.org
1510747289432   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from D:\Program Files\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1510747289437   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method install on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0
1510747289437   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-system-defaults:aushelper@mozilla.org visible
1510747289437   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
```

Comment: Please ensure that your combination of FF, Gecko Driver and Selenium are in the right combination. For 0.16.0 the minimum selenium version is 3.4 and the likely FF version is 52. For 0.19.0 the minimum selenium version is 55, and Python Selenium version is 3.5. It appears that you're running Selenium 3.3.1 which is rather old.

Comment: thanks @A.Kootstra I have created a new WorkBench in other system with config you mentioned.. it started working .. Thanks for your tip

Comment: Thanks @pankajmishra. you are right.. can you suggest which is most stable version among 3.4 and 3.6 ( i am looking at more usr base/popularity.. before i suggest to client)

Comment: I would prefer to go with latest selenium release..More often it's the geoco driver and Firefox which are causing troubles so you need to keep that in mind